# Trying to get event to fire on Dropdown Change

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am really battling to get a simple cascading `DropDown` to work. I am doing a very basic example, but it's failing. So I am trying to go right down to the basics to see how `events` tie to `controls`.

I have this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#CarMakeId').change(function () {
        alert("khsdhf")
    }); 
})
</script>

    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Index</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            Make: @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.CarMakeId,
                    new SelectList(Model.CarMakes, "Value", "Text"), 
                    "-- select make --") <br />
            Model: @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.CarModelId,
                     new SelectList(Model.CarModels, "Value", "Text"), 
                     "-- select model --")         
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

All I want it to do, for now, is alert me when I change a selection in my drop down. But I am getting `"Object expected`" in the `Java Script`.

Here is the rendered HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#CarMakeId').change(function () {
            alert("khsdhf");
        });
    })
</script>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
<form action="/" method="post">            <p>
            Make: <select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field CarMakeId must be a number." data-val-required="The CarMakeId field is required." id="CarMakeId" name="CarMakeId"><option value="">-- select make --</option>
<option value="1">BMW</option>
<option selected="selected" value="2">Ford</option>
<option value="3">Toyota</option>
</select>
            <br />
            Model: <select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field CarModelId must be a number." data-val-required="The CarModelId field is required." id="CarModelId" name="CarModelId"><option value="">-- select model --</option>
<option value="5">Mustang</option>
<option selected="selected" value="6">Territory</option>
<option value="7">Focus</option>
</select>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" title="Submit" />
        </p>
</form>    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Additional Info:

This is giving the same error:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("Hello");
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Place your javascript into a document.ready

Comment: Done - updated question, but still, same issue.

Comment: What is the generated HTML for your dropdown, is the ID CarMakeId? can you post it? Also, are you sure your jQuery is loaded?

Comment: I have added the rendered HTML.... Still getting the object error as the form loads (and when I press Submit).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `$(document).ready` to make sure that the dropdown exist before you add event handler.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#CarMakeId').change(function () {
        alert("khsdhf")
    });
}); 
</script>
```

`ready` will fire when the DOM is loaded. Read more here http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

Check for javascript errors on the page. it could be a missing semicolon ; at the end of the alert() line. you can also debug with 'Developer Tools' in IE9 or 'Firebug' in Firefox

Comment: in IE, tools, options there is an annoying but sometimes useful option "display a notification after every error on page".

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I didn't have the JQuery script link!

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```